# New Oculus Rift S installed on Windows 10 and now machine keeps crashing

Tags: technical-issues, pc, oculus-rift

Has anyone else experienced an issue with the Oculus Rift causing their PC to crash with the `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION` stop code error (BSOD)?  If so and you are experiencing the same issues that I am (shown below) can you please tell me what you did to make the system stable again with the Oculus app installed and the Oculus service enabled?

**System Build**

- Motherboard: ASUS P8P67 LE (BIOS: 3801)
- Memory: Crucial DDR3-1600 / PC3-12800 (8GB) x 2 (16GB total)
- Drive: Mushkin Reactor 1TB SSD
- CPU: Intel Core i5-3570K
- CPU Temps: Idle MIN: 26C MAX: 40C
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
- GPU Temps: Idle MIN: 28C MAX: 28C

---

**Under the application log in the event viewer I have:**
[image]

**Under the system log in the event viewer I have:**
[image]

`OVRServiceLauncher` (Oculus VR Service Launcher) seems to be the culprit.  As seen above (checking the time stamps), The last successful SYSTEM event that was posted was event id 158 (highlighted).  The next event was the first event that fired when the PC rebooted (event id 158).  So I know the issue had to have happened BEFORE 4:32:20PM.  Looking at the application log, I see the last entry before that time was by `OVRServiceLauncher` at 4:06:55PM.  It was trying to set the priority of the GPU.  It seems it was successful.  Then the next event id (4625) was right after the PC started up again.

Now, this alone would not make me think it was the `OVRServiceLauncher` app causing the issue.  I have been watching this thing reboot about every 30 minutes.  Each time I see the same last errors posted in the event viewer.

I have also at this point disabled the `OVRService` service so it does not start up on its own anymore and closed the `Steam` application.  Since I have done that I have not had a crash for well over 1 hour now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the issue was with the new Windows 10 update.  Version 1903 has some really bad issues apparently (and not just with Oculus). There is a workaround to getting the Oculus software to work with Windows 10 1903 though.  You have to run the `OVRServer_x64.exe` application (opens a command prompt and you see the service data) and leave it up while you play the Oculus Rifts.